# Browser extention fails connecting to local substrate node

Tags: frontier-node-template

I have a substrate based build running locally with RPC and JSON API, when attempting to connect via a browser extension to *http://127.0.0.1:9933*, getting the following error.

Error:

```
2023-03-01 14:16:36 Denied request: HttpHeaderRejected("origin", "moz-extension://b7930d0a-fa38-4693-86ff-101366b1a01b")
```

Node started as:

```
[12:46 PM] user@macOS  [~/src/discovery]./target/debug/substrate


2023-03-01 12:46:36 Substrate Node
2023-03-01 12:46:36 ✌️  version 3.0.0-dev-b8baa73f3e3
2023-03-01 12:46:36 ❤️  by Parity Technologies <admin@parity.io>, 2017-2023
2023-03-01 12:46:36  Chain specification: Local Testnet
2023-03-01 12:46:36   Node name: Alice
2023-03-01 12:46:36  Role: AUTHORITY
2023-03-01 12:46:36  Database: RocksDb at /Users/user/Library/Application Support/substrate/chains/local_testnet/db/full
2023-03-01 12:46:36 ⛓  Native runtime: node-268 (substrate-node-0.tx2.au10)
2023-03-01 12:47:46  Creating empty BABE epoch changes on what appears to be first startup.
2023-03-01 12:47:46 Using default protocol ID "sup" because none is configured in the chain specs
2023-03-01 12:47:46   Local node identity is: 12D3KooWKjFwQjfHF4m2rHL6fT9s6eoe7mfnUkpQy7SG9gASiBoY
2023-03-01 12:47:46  Operating system: macos
2023-03-01 12:47:46  CPU architecture: x86_64
2023-03-01 12:47:46  Highest known block at #0
2023-03-01 12:47:46 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615
2023-03-01 12:47:46 Running JSON-RPC HTTP server: addr=127.0.0.1:9933, allowed origins=Some(["http://localhost:*", "http://127.0.0.1:*", "https://localhost:*", "https://127.0.0.1:*", "https://polkadot.js.org"])
2023-03-01 12:47:46 Running JSON-RPC WS server: addr=127.0.0.1:9944, allowed origins=Some(["http://localhost:*", "http://127.0.0.1:*", "https://localhost:*", "https://127.0.0.1:*", "https://polkadot.js.org"])
2023-03-01 12:47:46  CPU score: 14MB/s
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your RPC is inaccessible here you can generally add one of the following:

- `--rpc-cors <origins>`
- `--unsafe-rpc-external`
- `--unsafe-rpc-external`

Although as AurevoirXavier says you probably only need the first one.

Source: https://docs.substrate.io/reference/command-line-tools/node-template/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the rpc-cors rule refused this.

Try running the node with `--rpc-cors all`.

Comment: This worked. Thank you !